# jQuery and Twitter Bootstrap function explanation

Tags: jquery, function, twitter

If you see the twitter's bootstrap application.js file that exists in all documents, you will notice something the following code:

```
!function( $ ) {
    ...
}( window.jQuery );
```

Could someone explain why this is the case for the first line of the code?

thanks

Answer (score 6):

It's a self executing function:

```
!function(x){}(y)
```

`x` is the parameter of the function and `y` is the parameter you pass in the *auto-call* of that function.

`!` is just a visual guide that tells you at a glance that the function is self executing. Another common practice is to wrap it in parenthesis instead. `(function(){}())`

Comment: "`!` is just a visual guide" That's not true. If a line starts with the word function then it is a function declaration (statement) and not a function expression. Removing the negation operator would result in a syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

That is because

```
function($) {} (window.jQuery);
```

is not valid in syntax, but

```
!function($) {} (window.jQuery);
```

is valid.

Now the question is why the first case is invalid?

Let's first take look at this. Both anonymous functions and named functions can be considered as a **expression**, e.g.

```
0 + function(y) { return y; } (1);
0 + function x(y) { return y; } (1);
```

are both valid.

Then consider this situation, this statement contain one expression

```
function x(y) {
    return y;
}
(1);
```

"That's incorrect!" may you say that because you know they are actually one function definition and one statement with one expression `(1)`.

The truth is, those codes is ambiguous to a grammar parser, because it could be resolved as either one function and one parenthesis-wrapped expression, or a function invocation. To avoid this kind of ambiguous, Javascript rules that **if `function` occurs as the first token of a statement, the statement ought to be a function definition**. So `function($) {} (window.jQuery);` is not valid in syntax because it's not a valid function definition. But prepose a `!` or even this kind code is valid

```
0 + function x(y) {
    return y;
}
(1);
```

It's one statement, with a binary plus, whose rhs is the function invocation, inside it.

Answer (score 2):

This guarantees that in the code inside the function you will be able to use the $ shorthand way of accessing jQuery.  In some environments (Wordpress for example), they don't have the $ shorthand "enabled" to avoid conflict with other javascript libraries.  By using this way here, you can use the simple $ construct in any environment (as long as window.jQuery is defined).

So, basically it creates a function and immediately calls it, passing in window.jQuery.  That means code in the function will see the $ local variable, and it's been assigned window.jQuery.