# What does ! $(function () { }(window.jQuery); means?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Reading the bootstrap code, i've found this: `! $(function () { }(window.jQuery);`.
What does it means?

Comment: could you show more context?

Comment: Self executing function, which can be achieved in a number of ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
!function($) { }(jQuery)
```

is the same as

```
(function($) { })(jQuery)
```

or

```
(function($) { }(jQuery))
```

It is just a shorter way to have a function expression that you can then immediately call. The not operator (`!`) makes it a function expression instead of a declaraction, just as the parenthesis do, but it is one character shorter.

Comment: *Just a shorter way to have a* **function expression**

Comment: Oh, so `!function ($)` wasn't the complete expression?

Comment: Oh, sounds good, and cleaner than the usual (function(){})(). thanks

Comment: I don't think it's cleaner at all. In fact, I find it confusing. When I see `!` I immediately associate it with the logical negation operator, and would expect that it negates the return value of the function. The parentheses seem much more clear.

Comment: While I agree with crush, it is highly debatable and subject to your style.

Comment: I would say it exists simply for code minimization purposes. As in, this shouldn't be used in your development code, but rather in your minimized, distributed library.

Comment: @crush I think it just because `function($) {} (window.jQuery);` is not a valid statement. In fact `+function($){}(window.jQuery);` does the same thing. For detail please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856288/jquery-and-twitter-bootstrap-function-explanation/15746510#15746510